# Problem with "suspend"

Tags: ati, dell, suspend

A few months ago I bought a Dell PowerEdge T320 (Intel Xeon E5-2403) which came with Windows Server 2012. I removed that and installed Ubuntu. But in Ubuntu when I try to put the system to suspend, it just flashes the screen off for a second an then takes me to the login screen. 
I thought it might be because of the on-board graphics card, so I added a discreet one (ATI 4850 - 512MB). But the problem wasn't there.

How do I solve it?

PS, I also tried Fedora but it had the same problem.

Comment: Can you run `sudo pm-suspend &> ~/suspendmsg` and (after logging in again) add the contents of the file (`~/suspendmsg`) to your question?

Comment: It is blank! Tried it twice. But the file is blank!

Comment: Can you return from suspend when executing `sudo pm-suspend` from TTY (Ctrl+Alt+F1)?

Comment: It didn't do anything. Not even flashing the screen off. It just stayed in the TTY1.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you installed Ubuntu on your main file disk. Otherwise that may cause some problems.

Try playing around with your power settings in Ubuntu. In my case with Lubuntu I would go to *Menu > Preferences > Power Manager* but you may have something different.

If that doesn't work, your computer may not be able to go into suspend/standby mode. Have you tried doing a temporary installation of Windows and trying to enter standby mode from there? Try doing this, and if the same kind of thing happens with Windows that happened with Ubuntu, your computer is phsyically not able to enter suspend/standby mode.

Comment: It used to go into "Sleep" in Windows.
And there aren't many options in Ubunu's power manager.

Comment: @SamanB.  Sleep is different from suspend. I believe what used to be called standby in Windows is now called hibernate. Because your computer came with a server OS it may not be able to enter suspend, since it would be a server-based computer.

Answer (score 1):

have you solved this problem? I had exactly the same issue on my laptop when I installed Ubuntu 14.10

I tracked it down to a bug in the kernel, at least in my case. Try using my kernel see if it fixes it. Suspend has been working with no issues for me for about a week now so I'll push the change upstream when I have a chance.

http://lyktoree.com/dragan/linux-image-3.16.7-ckt8_3.16.7-ckt8-10.00.Custom_amd64.deb

md5sum:
568d6ff307bc646b4f69a64375bbc8f1  linux-image-3.16.7-ckt8_3.16.7-ckt8-10.00.Custom_amd64.deb

Built for x86_64, hope it helps.

Comment: @Dragon-Stancevic No, unfortunately my problem is not solved yet. I'm kind of a noob in linux. I appreciate all the help from the community. Thanks a lot.

I will try your solution tomorrow.